# deduplication of slowly changing dimension data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Via the below code I try to describe my problem. Basically I want to go from slowly changing dimension data:

[image]

to some deduplicated data:

[image]

Obviously my actual data is bigger (more IDs and Values). In an ideal world I also want to avoid having to use the #Dates helper table if at all possible. My current attempt:

```
SELECT
    ID
    , Value1
    , Value2
    , MIN(#Dates.TheDate) AS StartDate
    , MAX(#Dates.TheDate) AS EndDate
FROM #Dates
INNER JOIN #Haves ON #Dates.TheDate BETWEEN #Haves.StartDate AND #Haves.EndDate
GROUP BY
    ID
    , Value1
    , Value2
```

does not produce the wants.

Code for replication:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Dates;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Haves') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Haves;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Wants') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Wants;

DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME;
SET @FromDate = '2020-01-01';
SET @ToDate = '2020-01-31';

-- all days in that period
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate)+1)
  TheDate = DATEADD(DAY, number, @FromDate)
INTO #Dates
FROM [master].dbo.spt_values
WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number;

SELECT * FROM #Dates

SELECT
    *
INTO #Haves
FROM (SELECT 1 ID, '2020-01-01' AS StartDate, '2020-01-03' AS EndDate, 1 Value1, 1 Value2
      UNION
      SELECT 1 ID, '2020-01-03' AS StartDate, '2020-01-05' AS EndDate, 1 Value1, 1 Value2
      UNION
      SELECT 1 ID, '2020-01-05' AS StartDate, '2020-01-07' AS EndDate, 3 Value1, 1 Value2
      UNION
      SELECT 1 ID, '2020-01-07' AS StartDate, '2999-01-01' AS EndDate, 1 Value1, 1 Value2
) AS IQ1;

SELECT * from #Haves

SELECT
    ID
    , Value1
    , Value2
    , MIN(#Dates.TheDate) AS StartDate
    , MAX(#Dates.TheDate) AS EndDate
FROM #Dates
INNER JOIN #Haves ON #Dates.TheDate BETWEEN #Haves.StartDate AND #Haves.EndDate
GROUP BY
    ID
    , Value1
    , Value2

SELECT
    *
INTO #Wants
FROM (SELECT 1 ID, '2020-01-01' AS StartDate, '2020-01-05' AS EndDate, 1 Value1, 1 Value2
      UNION
      SELECT 1 ID, '2020-01-05' AS StartDate, '2020-01-07' AS EndDate, 3 Value1, 1 Value2
      UNION
      SELECT 1 ID, '2020-01-07' AS StartDate, '2999-01-01' AS EndDate, 1 Value1, 1 Value2
) AS IQ1;

SELECT * FROM #Wants
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a gaps & islands problem. You want to detect groups of consecutive rows. Rows #1 and #2 in your screenshot are considered one group, because row #1's end date equals row #2's start date and id and value1 and value2 are equal.

So, let's detect all group changes first. Then just count the changes up to a row to get group numbers. Then aggregate to get the start and end date per group.

```
SELECT
  id,
  MIN(startdate) AS startdate,
  MAX(enddate) AS enddate,
  MIN(value1) AS value1,
  MIN(value2) AS value2
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id, startdate, enddate, value1, value2,
    SUM(chg) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) AS grp
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id, startdate, enddate, value1, value2,
      CASE WHEN startdate = LAG(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate)
            AND value1    = LAG(value1)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate)
            AND value2    = LAG(value2)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate)
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
      END AS chg
    FROM #Haves
  ) with_change_flags
) with_groups
GROUP BY id, grp
ORDER BY id, grp;
```

Comment: Thanks I was aware of the gaps & islands problem and tried some code I found without success. I will have a look. Thanks!

Comment: could it be that AND value2    = lag(value1)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) shoul dbe AND value2    = lag(value2)  OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate)?

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry. I've corrected this.

Comment: thanks - just checking if it works with the actual data - thanks!!!!

Comment: I found another flaw it does not work if there are null entries ...

Comment: I don't consider this a flaw. You never mentioned nulls, and the query treats nulls as is common in SQL: A null is not considered equal to another value, even if that other value itself is a null.

Comment: I mainly left it for other people - I do a COALESCE